# Format change when list is given as column names

Tags: r, lubridate

I have created list of intervals from below code.

```
library(lubridate)    
date1 <- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 05:30:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
shifts <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date1+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = c(0,150,390,570,690,810,1050), z = c(600,570,600,600,600,600,600), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})
```

I have another data set df  with 105 columns.

I am trying to give column names as shifts intervals.

But the format is changing. I want my column names as same as shifts. I am trying as below.

```
list <- unlist(shifts, recursive = FALSE)

colnames(df)<-as.date(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because `list` is still of type `interval`. If you want to use the contents of this `interval` as `colnames`, you need to convert them to a `list` of characters like this:

```
list <- unlist(shifts, recursive = FALSE)
dmy <- list()
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    foo <- c(list[[i]])
    foo <- as.character(foo)
    dmy <- append(dmy, foo)
}
colnames(df) <- dmy # list of characters
```

Output:

```
> class(list[[1]])
[1] "Interval"
attr(,"package")
[1] "lubridate"
> class(dmy[[1]])
[1] "character"
```

Now you should be able to rename columns of `df` :)